# Clicking flipping image in selenium webdriver using C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

New to this platform I'm a beginner learning selenium webdriver with c# but I have a problem clicking on a flipping image, I identify the id but it won't click on it. I was told to use wait which really didn't work.
I've used this wait and other ones as listed below:

```
WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
waits.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("LinkToHomepage"))).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("homepageLink")).Click();
var waits = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));


IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("homeLink"));
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(input).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the html code of the element you are trying to click as well as the error you're getting. That will help us to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use an offset from the element and a static click.  If it finds the element then moving down and to the right should put the pointer in the middle of the element then just send a click command.  Or the click offset with the element passed in.